# What are these corruption stacks?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I just spent some time in the Brand in the Fields of Ruin. While I was there, I managed to attain 12 stacks of "Corruption", for which the tooltip says only "Your conditions do more damage."

Are these harmful to me in any way? How do I get them to go away?

Comment: Does your weapon have a [Sigil of Corruption](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Sigil_of_Corruption) in it, by any chance?

Comment: @Fluttershy So it does. I thought it had to do with the Brand because that's the first time I noticed it. It was on my less-often-used weapon, which is why it stopped going up after I left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would appear that you're using a weapon with a [Sigil of Corruption](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Sigil_of_Corruption).

This will increase the amount of Condition Damage you deal with every stack, up to a maximum of 25 stacks. Stacks are obtained by killing an enemy with said weapon.

It is not harmful to you in anyway, but rather, it is beneficial! If you want it to go away, regardless, simply zone and you will lose all stacks you have acquired.

Comment: Probably not an ideal way to get rid of them (not that you'd want to), but do note that the stacks disappear if you become Downed.

Comment: Can't you just unequip the weapon, also?

Comment: @RavenDreamer You can unequip the weapon, but the stacks will stick around. You just won't gain any more stacks.

Comment: @Fluttershy Note to self, then: Get a stack weapon, then switch to another sigil when fully stacked.